# How do I install gnome-shell-extensions package in Ubuntu Quantal

Tags: gnome, command-line, 12.10, gnome-shell-extension

Im looking for a way to install the User-Theme extension in Ubuntu Quantal with gnome 3.6 and from my understanding you need to install the gnome-shell-extensions package.

I'm unable to find any compatible version of this anywhere thats not going to give me dependency errors or broke my system.

If anyone knows how to help me out, could you please let me know.

Comment: I am closing this as too localized because the recent update to `gnome-shell-extensions` should help you install it at the moment. (Source: I am running Quantal).

Comment: shell extension or shell theme?

Answer (score 0):

Hi look at this [page](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/quantal/universe/base/gnome-shell-extensions) , its having gnome-extensions package for Ubuntu 12.10 .

Answer (score 0):

You can install all extensions you want from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/ , just browse it with either firefox or chrome/chromium and flip the switch to "ON".

Since today, even the user theme extension is working for me in quantal.

The packages for quantal did not work for me, and the gnome advanced settings is now called gnome tweak tool.